# I use jquery to drag and move an image but after several moves the movement became slow and slow ? why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this jquery code (without UI), first time I drag and move the image it's moves smoothly but 2d time it moves slow 3d time more slow and so on... anything wrong with the code? anything to release?

```
(function($) 
    {
      $.fn.drags = function(opt) 
      {
        opt = $.extend({handle:"",cursor:"pointer"}, opt);      
        if(opt.handle === "") 
        {
          var $el = this;
        } 
        else 
        {
          var $el = this.find(opt.handle);
        }

        $(this).css('cursor', opt.cursor).on("mousedown", function(e) 
        {         
          if(opt.handle === "") 
          {
            var $drag = $(this).addClass('draggable');
          } 
          else 
          {
            var $drag = $(this).addClass('active-handle').parent().addClass('draggable');
          }
          var z_idx = $drag.css('z-index'), drg_w = $drag.outerWidth(), pos_x = $drag.offset().left + drg_w - e.pageX;              
          $drag.css('z-index', 1000).parents().on("mousemove", function(e) 
          {
            if($drag.offset().left<438)
            {                
                 pos_x =438 + drg_w - e.pageX;
                 $('.draggable').offset({left:e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w});                                 
                return;
            }
            else if($drag.offset().left>701)
            {               
                pos_x =701 + drg_w - e.pageX;
                $('.draggable').offset({left:e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w});
                return;
            }
            else
            {               
                 $('.draggable').offset({left:e.pageX + pos_x - drg_w}).on("mouseup", function() {$(this).removeClass('draggable').css('z-index', z_idx);});
                 $('#rbba_prgrs').width($drag.offset().left-438);
            } 
          });
        e.preventDefault(); // disable selection 
        }).on("mouseup", function() 
        { 
             if(opt.handle === "") 
             {
              $(this).removeClass('draggable');
             } 
             else 
             {
              $(this).removeClass('active-handle').parent().removeClass('draggable');
             }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like everytime "mousedown" is being called, it attaches event listener function for mousemove. This is done repeatedly, and after a while, it would have to perform that function multiple times on each mouse pixel movement. Find a way to attach that listener elsewhere.

Comment: I remove the listener of 'mousemove' just before binding it using $drag.parents().unbind("mousemove"); it works fine:-) thank you...:-)